# Is it a good practice to make header redirections inside class' methods?

Tags: php, mysql

i just want to know if It is a good practica to make redirections inside a php class method, for example if I'm searching inside a database an specific ID but it doesnt find it, make a redirect instead of a return false and catch that false inside other script and make the redirection there?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think good vs bad practice may be too subjective.

Doing two completely different things violates the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) because:

- Your class has the responsibility of making redirects AND searching for data, what if you needed to expose your database classes as a TCP server or through a CLI??
- When the two things are coupled together changing the database fetching code requires re-verifying that http redirects work correctly! something completely unrelated

As you mentioned in your question, one way to fix it could be to separate the redirect and the database logic, and have your script compose both of them, it would call the database, and if an error/empty response came back it would redirect, allowing your database object to only change when database logic changes, and your redirect logic only changing when redirect logic changes.